# Как передать переменную из одной форму в другую на js и целесообразно так делать?

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте! Суть вопроса в следующем -есть страница на которой находиться форма - где вводиться email - после ввода которого пользователь попадает на вторую страницу - где есть другая форма. Подскажите как реализовать передачу переменной из одной формы в другую на js, если это возможно.
Заранее спасибо!!

Дополнительно:

Имя, фамилия и Email введен - данные отправлены. Переход на вторую форму - url имееет следующий вид http://site.com/choice/?&name-first=%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9&name-last=%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2&email=dima%40mail.ru&2=%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B02%D1%80%D1%83

как получить данные из url?

Comment: а в чем проблема-то?

Comment: это целесообразно делать вообще?

Comment: @soledar10 опишите подробнее, что у вас конкретно вызывает сомнения. Если вы делаете переход на страницу на клиенте (что-нибудь типа **window.location = ...**) то разумеется это нужно делать на js. Если ваш переход происходит путем обращения к серверу и последующим редиректом на новую страницу, то разумеется это стоит делать, передавая необходимые параметры через ответ сервера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно с помощью js получать данные из url, то можно воспользоваться этой функцией:

```
function getUrlParams() {  
  var res = {};
  var paramsStr = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&').filter(function(it) { return it != ''; } );
  var params = paramsStr.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var paramPair = params[i].split("=");       
    if (typeof res[paramPair[0]] === "undefined") {
      res[paramPair[0]] = paramPair[1];     
    } else if (typeof res[paramPair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ res[paramPair[0]], paramPair[1] ];
      res[paramPair[0]] = arr;      
    } else {
      res[paramPair[0]].push(paramPair[1]);
    }
  } 
    return res;
};
```